# UsoClient cannot find windows updates, but a manual scan does

Tags: windows, powershell

I use this script:

```
UsoClient.exe StartScan
UsoClient.exe StartDownload
UsoClient.exe StartInstall
```

I opened the windows update window before I run the code to see what will be do.
It starts scan about 1ms and write out, No new updates available at the moment. 
If I manually start san to press the start now button it founds some updates and installs it.

Why? What is the wrong with the code?

Comment: There's no code involved here, you're just running a program from the command line.

Comment: This isn't a coding question - voting to close and move to [su] as this is about windows updates.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using this method instead. It is a PowerShell Windows Update module that is specifically made for this task. Intructions/code is below.

1) Verify that you have PowerShell 5 or newer, this is required

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

2) Run PowerShell as admin and run the following

```
 Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
```

3) Register to use the Microsoft Update Service instead of the standard Windows Update Service

```
Add-WUServiceManager -ServiceID 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d
```

4) You should now be able to run the following command, which (by the parameters) will go searching for windows updates and install all of them that are available. I recommend looking at the help for `Get-WUInstall` to view what options are available to use and reboot the machine if necessary.

```
Get-WUInstall –MicrosoftUpdate –AcceptAll –AutoReboot
```

Comment: It's not great to just link to a blog/article as sites often disappear, once this happens your answer isn't useful to anyone in the future. I would recommend taking the code from that article and adding it to your answer with a decent explanation as this keeps it useful in the future.

Comment: I would like to make it automatic. How can I install the custom module automatically without type the 'Y' for the question?

Comment: You will only need to install the module once per machine, so setting it in a script to run everytime you want to install updates is not a good idea. I would do it manually on whatever machines you need to use it on, then create a script to install updates. You could do this by using `enter-pssession -computername yourcomputername` and running steps 1 through 3.

Answer (score 0):

control update
usoclient StartInteractiveScan

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).